# my phone is not recognized as Android devices in android studio

Tags: android, connection, device

There's so many similar questions . "download the driver that fits your android" was the most common answer..
but for me this is not the answer.
first of all, I downloaded the lastest version of samsung driver.(my android is galaxy)
second I downloaded ADB and the path is correct .
third, I already downloaded the google USB driver too.
fourth, USB debugging mode is on in my android phone.

I am in window 10
[image]

i used 'troubleshoot device connections' option.

and i noticed that android studio do not recognized my galaxy note 10 as Android device .
(although my computer recognized it)

I'm struggling with this problem almost half a day. and im going crazy..
can anyone help me?

Comment: i tried to figure out what was wrong. and i guess the samsung driver is not working in my computer